# How to identify to which IP the FQDN is resolved in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, dns

I am using https:///path to send the queries from Jmeter to the application.
The FQDN is configured with 2 IPs.
I need to know, to which IP my FQDN is resolved for each sample.
Can we get the IP to which FQDN is resolved in JMeter listner?

Answer (score 0):

If your server doesn't return its IP address in the response headers or body - you won't be able to get it from the "lisnter" (whatever it is)

However you can get this information from jmeter.log file if you:

1. Add [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your test plan
2. [Enable debug logging](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for it by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.DNSCacheManager" level="debug" />
   ```

This way you will be able to see what are underlying IP addresses behind the system under test domain name

[image]

Anyway you will need to add the DNS Cache Manager (or at least [disable DNS caching](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420655--Disable-DNS-caching)) otherwise you will always be hitting only one IP address which will be cached on JVM level.